# How to remove bullet in Html using css in php

Tags: html, css

i am trying to display images in gallery using ul ,li in html

list items are iterated through while loop

```
<ul style="list-style-type: none;">
while($data=mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
$path=$data[1];
<li style="list-style:none; float: left; margin-left:4px; margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px;">
<div><img src=<?=$path?> width=300 height=240></img></div>
</li>
}
</ul>
```

but ul tag display one bullet at beggining

please help me

Comment: no need for <div> inside <li> really and also you can close <img /> short.

Answer (score 3):

```
ul, ul li {
   list-style:none;
 }
```

style it with CSS

Comment: Might want to revise that to `ul, ul li { list-style: none; }` to catch both.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any obvious reason why it's putting an erroneous bullet into your page, however there are a couple of things you may want to tidy up first to rule them out.

Firstly, there is no  closing tag. Image elements close themselves with a trailing slash.

Secondly, why are you enclosing some attributes in quotes and not others? Start getting used to good practice and enclosing all attributes in quotes.

Also, you should separate you style from your markup using a stylesheet:

```
ul, ul li {
    list-style:none;
}

li {
    float: left;
    margin-left:4px;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

Also, a tip for the PHP is to use `while: ... endwhile;` as it is more readable:

```
<ul>
    <?php
    while($data=mysql_fetch_row($result)) :
    {
        $path=$data[1];
    ?>
        <li>
             <div><img src="<?=$path?>" width="300" height="240" /></div>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

While editing your code, I also noticed that you didn't enclose the while loop in php tags. I assume you're enclosing it properly in php tags in your real application?

Neal